# Negatively curved manifolds with many totally geodesic submanifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I'm curious about the following question and have not been able to find any literature on the topic: Suppose that $M$ is a closed negatively curved Riemannian manifold with a "large" quantity of totally geodesic submanifolds. Is there anything one can say about such a manifold?

To be more precise, consider such an $M$ (diffeomorphic to a complex hyperbolic manifold) carrying an almost complex structure $J$ which looks like a complex hyperbolic manifold in the following sense: for each $x \in M$ and each $v \in T_{x}M$ there is a totally geodesic surface $S$ tangent to the plane spanned by $v$ and $J(v)$ at $x$. It seems to be a natural question to ask if $M$ is itself complex hyperbolic (which would follow for example if $M$ was a Kahler manifold). I have no intuition as to whether this should be an easy or difficult problem so I'm curious (and thankful in advance) if anyone has some guidance/references.

Edit: I have made my question in the second paragraph more explicit below, since I think the original version may be ambiguous,

Let $X$ be a compact quotient of complex hyperbolic space $\mathbb{C} H^{n}$ ($n \geq 2$). Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold obtained by taking a small smooth perturbation of the symmetric metric on $X$ (same underlying space, different metrics). Now suppose we are given an almost complex structure $J$ - not necessarily the standard one - such that for each $x \in M$ and each $v \in T_{x}M$ there is a totally geodesic subsurface $S$ of $M$ which is tangent to the plane spanned by $v$ and $J(v)$ inside of $T_{x}M$. Is $M$ isometric (up to rescaling) to $X$?

As far as I can tell from searching, Riemannian manifolds typically have very few higher dimensional totally geodesic submanifolds so the condition being imposed above is quite strong.

Edit 2: As pointed out in the comments, I actually want to assume these subsurfaces are also $J$-holomorphic, i.e., $TS \subset TM$ is preserved by $J$ for each surface $S$.

Comment: Are you assuming that $J$ is orthogonal with respect to the underlying metric?

Comment: Do you have any actual examples of such? (other than $\mathbb{C}P^n?$

Comment: @IgorRivin the example I have in mind is a cocompact quotient of the noncompact dual $\mathbb{C}H^{n}$ of $\mathbb{C}P^{n}$.

Comment: A product of complex hyperbolic manifolds is not complex hyperbolic, if by complex hyperbolic you mean locally isometric to $\mathbb{CH}^n$.

Comment: @Ben Strictly speaking this is prohibited by my imposing a negative curvature condition on $M$, but this seems to be a good example to keep in mind. For context: this question arose for me in considering some rigidity questions in hyperbolic dynamics, so the negative curvature condition is being carried over from there (since negative curvature $\rightarrow$ geodesic flow is Anosov). I have in mind metrics on $M$ which are obtained as small perturbations of the symmetric metric.

Comment: @Clark: Since you aren't assuming that the almost complex structure $J$
 is related to the metric in any way, one can construct trivial examples that are not complex hyperbolic space forms: Take a real compact hyperbolic manifold $M^{2n}$ whose tangent bundle admits some almost complex structure $J$. Then, since every tangent $2$-plane is tangent to a totally geodesic surface, there is such a surface tangent to every $J$-invariant $2$-plane. Since the real hyperbolic $2n$-ball is not isometric to $\mathbb{CH}^n$ (even locally), this is a new example.

Comment: @Clark:  Are you going to assume that the totally geodesic surfaces in $M$ are $J$-holomorphic?  (Just from your stated assumptions, each of these totally geodesic surfaces only has to have one point that has a $J$-complex tangent space.)

Comment: @Robert: Yes, that's what I had in mind.

Comment: Here is a reference that could be useful: O. Kassabov. On the axiom of planes and the axiom of spheres in th
e almost Hermitian geometry.
Serdica
,
8
, 1982, 109-114.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a partial answer:  Let $(M^{2n},g,J)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold endowed with a *$g$-orthogonal* almost complex structure $J$ with the property that, for every nonzero $v\in T_pM$ there exists a $J$-holomorphic curve $C\subset M$ passing through $p$ with tangent space spanned by $v$ and $Jv$ that is totally geodesic.  Moreover, suppose that the scalar curvature of $g$ is negative.  Then, up to a constant scale factor, $(M,g,J)$ is isomorphic to a compact quotient of $\mathbb{CH}^n$.

Note that the only additional hypotheses that I have added to the OP's problem are that the almost complex structure $J$ be $g$-orthogonal *and* that the totally geodesic surfaces should be $J$-holomorphic.

The argument goes as follows:

First, one shows by a local calculation that, if $(M^{2n},g,J)$ has the desired property of having sufficiently many totally $g$-geodesic surfaces that are $J$-holomorphic curves that there is one tangent to each $J$-complex line in $TM$, then $(M^{2n},g,J)$ must be nearly Kähler.

Second, a complete, simply-connected nearly Kähler manifold is known to be the product of a Kahler manifold and a *strict* nearly Kähler manifold.  (See Proposition 2.1 of (*Nearly Kähler geometry and Riemannian foliations*, by Paul-Andi Nagy, arXiv:math/0203038v1).  Meanwhile, by a theorem of Paul-Andi Nagy (*On nearly Kähler geometry*, arXiv:math/0110065), if $(N^{2n},g,J)$ is a complete strict nearly Kähler, then the scalar curvature of $g$ is constant and strictly positive.  Since we are assuming that our given compact $(M^{2n},g,J)$ has negative curvature, it follows that its simply connected cover cannot have any strict nearly Kähler factor.  Hence, $(M^{2n},g,J)$ must be Kähler.

Third, once one is in the Kähler category, it is easy to show that the existence of totally geodesic $J$-holomorphic curves tangent to every complex line implies that the metric has constant holomorphic sectional curvature, i.e., it is a complex 'space form'.  Since the curvature is negative, it follows that, up to scale, it must be isometric to the standard Kähler structure on $\mathbb{CH}^n$.

Note:  Without the negative curvature assumption, there do exist strictly nearly Kähler examples.  E.g., the $6$-sphere with its standard $\mathrm{G}_2$-invariant metric and (non-integrable) almost complex structure has a totally geodesic $2$-sphere tangent to any given complex line in its tangent space.

Comment: Thanks! I checked the situation I was considering and my structure $J$ is indeed $g$-orthogonal; as edited in my post, I am also assuming that these totally geodesic surfaces are $J$-holomorphic. So this does give a complete answer to the question I originally had in mind.

Comment: @Clark:  If you are interested in seeing the details of any of the steps in the above argument, let me know.  When I have time, I can put them in; they aren't that hard.

Comment: I believe I can fill in the details, although I want to clarify a few things since I don't really know much complex geometry. It looks like the proof could also be arranged to say "nearly Kahler + negative sectional curvature => complex space form" since compact negatively curved Kahler manifolds are all biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}H^{n}$ and in this case the $J$-holomorphic surfaces are only used at the beginning to get the nearly Kahler condition. The first and third steps appear to be local Riemannian geometry calculations which I can do.

Comment: I also am curious to know if the theorems of Paul-Andi Nagy as applied here necessarily need to use global properties of the metric as opposed to local calculations.

Comment: @Clark:  If I remember correctly, the result is that a nearly Kähler manifold is locally a product of a Kähler manifold and a strict nearly Kähler manifold, i.e., you don't need compactness or completeness for that.  You do need the   totally geodesic $J$-holomorphic curves in part three to get constant holomorphic sectional curvature, though.  So, yes, I think that the whole thing can be done locally without assuming negative sectional curvature.  The change is that now you'll have to add in the $G_2$-invariant nearly Kähler $S^6$ as a (local) solution.